# Rails not finding value using !=

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.0.9 (Ruby 1.9.2, MySQL) I have a method that is supposed to find users using two fields, type(string) and flag(boolean).  The string part of the query works fine, but not the boolean part.

here's the code:

```
def find_users(type)
  @private_users = User.where('type =? and flag != ?', org_type, true)
end
```

to try to figure out what's going on, put this code:

```
@users.each do |f|
  puts "oh helllllllllllllllllllllllllllo #{f.user_name}"      
  puts "oh helllllllllllllllllllllllllllo #{f.flag}" 
  puts "oh helllllllllllllllllllllllllllo #{f.type}"
end
```

The flag field is blank/null for most of these and those are the ones I'm trying to pick up.

If I change the expression to `('type =? and flag = ?', type, true)`, it correctly finds the ones where 1 is the value of the flag.

I've tried these things to no avail:

```
 User.where('type =? and flag = ?', org_type, false)
 User.where('type =? and flag = ?', org_type, "")
 User.where('type =? and flag = ?', org_type, nil)
```

This probably an easy question for someone, so I hoping some knows the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
User.where(:type => org_type, flag: nil)
```

Should result in the SQL query

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" = 'some_type' AND "users"."flag" IS NULL
```

The key being that ActiveRecord will use the `IS NULL` operator for your `flag` column.

Answer (score 1):

If a nullable column is `NULL`, you can't use normal comparison operators. You need to use the `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` operator.

You can also try the [`NULL`-safe equals (`<=>`)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator (which is a new one to me too)